# How to successfully use dynamic array to pass parameter with mutithread

Tags: c++

```
void * bubbleSort(void * data){
  int * str;
  str = (int* ) data;
  int temp = 0;
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < len ; i++ ){
        for (int j = i + 1; j < len ; j++ ){
            if(str[i] > str[j]){
                temp = str[i];
                str[i] = str[j];
                str[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(){
  int *data= new int[1000000];
  ...
  pthread_t thread[input];
   for ( int i = 0 ; i < input ; i ++){
     pthread_create(&thread[i],NULL,bubbleSort,arguments);  
     pthread_join(thread[i],NULL);
 }
}
```

I have `int *data[1000000]` and I want to use pthread to pass parameter to bubble sort.

The above is the code I wrote, but it is no output

How to successfully work ?

Comment: Can you explain in English what you are trying to do? How many threads do you want to spawn and what should each thread do?

Comment: @Botje I want to use pthread to execute bubble sort. I will key in a input by keyboard. No matter how many threads.

Comment: And the other two questions? you seem to want to spawn more than one thread. What should each thread do?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? You get compiler error? Runtime error (e.g. segmentation fault)?

Comment: @Botje I want to create more than one thread and pass int * data[100000]  to bubble sort.

Comment: @Kia For the third and final time: what should each thread do? If each thread starts bubblesorting the full array you're going to run into horrible data races and corruption.

Comment: Note than `int *data[10000];` is creating 10000 pointers to `int`. You have to drop the `*` to get an array of 10000 integers: `int data[10000];`

Comment: @Botje Sorry, my English not well.  I want to create more than one thread.There are a lot of data from notepad, and I want to divide data into K copies. and use K thread execute bubble sort.

Comment: Are you aware that this is a very hard problem? You will have to exchange values between threads with the appropriate synchronization and locking to ensure one thread doesn't start trashing another thread's part of the array.

Answer (score 1):

To fix your immediate problem: your `data` variable is defined with the wrong type.
`int *data[1000]` is an array of 1000 `int *`, which decays to `int**`. Your `bubbleSort` function expects an `int *`.

Declare `data` as follows instead:

```
int * data = new int[10000];
```

and then you can simply pass it to `pthread_create` as a `void*` like you do now.

However, modern C++ has a `std::thread` which is far easier to work with:

```
std::thread sorter(bubbleSort, data);
sorter.join();
```

Comment: Oops, I didn't upload new int[1000]. Now I use std::thread sorter.... but it still no output

Comment: Edit your question into a [mcve]. The version you posted is of course a no-op.